# Keras autoencoder reconstruction error per feature

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I saw that h2o have a anomaly parameter reconstruction error per feature, do Keras have such option? I want to change few cases in my test dataset which will have significantly larger reconstruction error, so I was thinking that RE per feature will help me or you have another suggestion for impacting RE? My model accuracy is pretty good, I think:
0s - loss: 0.0768 - acc: 0.9563 - val_loss: 0.1227 - val_acc: 0.9522

Comment: Watch out when using accuracy as your metric. If you are doing anomaly detection chances are your dataset is highly skewed (that is really few anomaly examples). If this is true, accuracy may be a biased metric as your model can decide to classify *always* as non-anomaly and still get a good accuracy (as proportionally your training set most surely has a lot of non-anomalies). Other useful metrics may be Precision and Recall. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you on your comment. Yes you are right with small correction, I WILL try anomaly detecion but,  at in this phase I got accuracy without y variable i.e.  class
history = autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train,
                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=False, # bilo je True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, X_test),
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]).history

Comment: Now I want to create anomaly i.e. change the features of few cases, mark that rows with 1 which will mean anomaly class.  What I do not know is how to change the cases to cause a pretty large reconstruction error relatively  to the RE of the rest of the dataset.

Comment: Ill see if I can answer tomorrow (its late here). I also see that your last comment is actually asking something else to what your posts says. Could you try to edit your Question to put clearly what you are trying to do or your desired outcome? Also, showing what you have done can greatly help in case you have errors, so your question does not fall as too broad.

Comment: I think that is the best that my question about _RE per feature_ stay open. Generating anomaly is the next question closed to the solving my question above, I think.

Comment: I asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968304/autoencoder-float-variables-dominate-over-binaries about domination of some features in autoencoder model